Giving two functionals that extends another

Let denote $M:=\{ (x_n) \in l^1 \, | \, \forall n \in \Bbb{N} : x_{2n} = 0 \} $ . Prove that there are functionals $f \in M'$ and $f_1, f_2 \in l_1'$ such that $f_1 \neq f_2$ and $\forall j \in \{ 1, 2 \}: f_j |_M = f \land \lVert f_j \rVert = \lVert f \rVert $ . Why does this not contradicts the Hahn-Banach Theorem ?

I am doing this excercise and I want to know if I am proving it correctly, so any confirmation or correction would be appreciated.
First, note that $l_1 ' = l_\infty $, that is: for all $f \in E ' $ there is a sequence $y = (y_k) \in l_\infty$ such that $f((x_n)) = \sum_n x_n y_n $ .
So, take some $f \in M'$ and extend it by Hahn Banach to $f_1 \in l_1'$ with $\lVert f_1 \rVert = \lVert f \rVert $. Then, for some $y=(y_n) \in l_\infty$ it has that $f_1 ((x_n)) = \sum_n x_n y_n$ . Then, for $x = (x_n) \in M$ it has that $f_1 (x) = f (x) = \sum_n x_n y_n = \sum_k x_{2k-1} y_{2k-1} $. Let denote $f_2 : l_1 \rightarrow \Bbb{K}$ as $f_2 ((x_n)) = \sum_k x_{2k-1} y_{2k-1}$ . It is clear that $f_2 |_M = f$ and $f_1 \neq f_2$.
By Hölder's Inequality, given $x= (x_n) \in l_1$ we have $ |f_2 (x)| = |\sum_k x_{2k-1} y_{2k-1} | \leq \sum_k | x_{2k-1} y_{2k-1} | \leq \sum_n | x_n y_n | \leq \lVert y \rVert_\infty \lVert x \rVert_1 \implies \lVert f_2 \rVert \leq \lVert y \rVert _\infty = \lVert f \rVert $ . On the other hand, given $x = (x_n) \in M $ it occurs $ | f(x) | = | f_2 (x) | \leq \lVert f_2 \rVert \cdot \lVert x \rVert_1 \implies \lVert f \rVert \leq \lVert f_2 \rVert $ and we would have finished.
This does not contradict the Hahn-Banach Theorem since this theorem does not ensure unicity.

In this particular case you do not need to apply the HB theorem. Instead you can provide explicit examples of two functionals. For example $f(x)=x_1,$ $f_1(x)=x_1$ and $f_2(x)=x_1+x_2.$ In your proof there is no guarrantee that $f_1\neq f_2$ because it may occur that $y_{2n}=0$ for all $n.$ You need to slightly modify $f_1.$

@RyszardSzwarc Nice, thank you so much!
